# Arbitrary Smooth structure

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Is it possible to give a smooth structure to any objects? Say two lines intersecting at a point. It seems there is a smooth structure though at the intersecting point it is not locally euclidean if one views it in $R^2$. Is there a limit at which one cannot assign smooth structure?

Comment: You may be interested in the notion of [diffeological spaces](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffeology).

Answer (score 2):

It is not always possible to assign a smooth structure to a geometric object, even if it is locally Euclidean. There exist [4-manifolds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4-manifold) with no possible smooth structure.